# every relation in a special structure $M$ which is first-order definable with parameters has cardinality $< \omega$ or $= |M|$.

Tags: first-order-logic, model-theory

Let $M$ be a special structure. I'm trying to proof that every relation in $M$ which is first-order definable with parameters has cardinality $< \omega$ or $= \lambda$.

By a first-order definable with parameters relation I mean a set $A = \left \{ \psi(a_1, \cdots, a_m, b_1, \cdots, b_n): a_1, \cdots, a_m \in M,\, b_1, \cdots, b_n \in X, \, \psi(\overline a, \overline y) \text{ formula} \right \}$ for fixed $m$ and $X \subset M$.

I don't know even how to start this question. If I suppose that a set $A$ as above has cardinality $\geq \omega$, we proof that $|A| = |M|$, but how can I proceed?

Comment: What is a special structure?

Comment: @asaf The definition I know is that a structure $A$ of infinite cardinality $\kappa$ is special if it is the union (colimit) of an elementary chain $(A_i)_{i < \kappa}$ where each $A_i$ is $|i|^+$-saturated.

Comment: @Mark: I thought you're on a plane.

Comment: @asaf there is lots of downtime around a flight. For example, now I actually found the time to write an answer.

Comment: @Mark: And yet you didn't have any time to find the shift key and write `Asaf`... tsk tsk tsk.

Comment: @asaf i'm on my phone, so i can't be bothered

Comment: @Mark: I've never been more ashamed in my life as I am now, of the fact that we are in the same logic group.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In this answer I will not distinguish between elements/variables and finite tuples of elements/variables (so you may read every lowercase letter as if it denotes a finite tuple).

First I should say that your definition of "definable" it's not quite right. The way you defined it, every set would be definable. The correct definition is that $A$ is definable (in $M$) if there is a formula $\phi(x,y)$ and $b \in M$ such that
$$
A = \{a \in M : M \models \phi(a,b)\}.
$$
We call $b$ the *parameters*.

Let me also recall the definition of a special structure here (to introduce some notation at the same time). A structure $M$ of infinite cardinality $\kappa$ is special if it is the union $\bigcup_{i < \kappa} M_i$ of a chain $(M_i)_{i < \kappa}$ such that for every $i < \kappa$ the structure $M_i$ is $|i|^+$-saturated.

Now that is out of the way, we can actually have a look at your question.
Let $A \subseteq M$ be infinite and $|A| < |M|$. Suppose that $A$ is definable by some $\phi(x, y)$ with parameters $b$. We will aim for a contradiction. Since $b$ is just a finite tuple of parameters, there will be some $\lambda < \kappa$ such that $b \in M_\lambda$. We may assume that $|A| \leq \lambda$ (otherwise replace $\lambda$ by $|A|$). Now define
$$
\Sigma(x) = \{x \neq a : a \in A \cap M_\lambda\} \cup \{\phi(x, b)\},
$$
then clearly $\Sigma(x)$ is finitely satisfiable. So we can extend $\Sigma(x)$ to a complete type $p(x)$ over $(A \cap M_\lambda) \cup \{b\}$. Since $|(A \cap M_\lambda) \cup \{b\}| < \lambda^+$ and $M_\lambda$ is $\lambda^+$-saturated we then must be able to find a realisation $c \in M_\lambda$ of $p(x)$ and thus of $\Sigma(x)$. But that means $M_\lambda \models \phi(c, b)$, so $c \in A \cap M_\lambda$ while the first part of $\Sigma(x)$ says that $c$ must be different from every element in $A \cap M_\lambda$. We thus reach our desired contradiction, and we can conclude that of $A$ is infinite and $|A| < |M|$, then $A$ cannot be definable in $M$.

Comment: Not every special structure is saturated, though...

Comment: @Alex Ah, you are right, I guess I assumed that the structure has regular cardinality, which makes the question more general than I first thought. So then we will need to replicate the argument in one of the structures in the chain, I will edit my answer.

Comment: Right - the point is that special models (of singular cardinality) provably exist in ZFC for all theories, while saturated models do not.

Comment: @Alex That is indeed a very good reason for this version. I have corrected my answer. Thank you for your input!

Comment: Sorry for the delay to respond. But your $\kappa$ in the fourth paragraph means $|M|$?

Comment: @MarkKamsma  I'm stucked in two parts. 1) Why can you say that your $\sum$ is finitely satisfiable? and 2) Is it by compactness that you can extend to a complete type $p$?

Comment: @user242964 yes, I defined $\kappa$ as $|M|$ in the paragraph before. For your other questions. (1) We use here that $A$ is infinite, so every finite part of $\Sigma(x)$ will say at most "$x$ is in $A$ but unequal to a finite part of it". So then we can definitely find some realisation of that. (2) If something is finitely satisfiable it must have a realisation in some elementary extension (indeed by compactness), then taking the type of that realisation is a completion.

Comment: @user242964 For (1) it may also be good to note why $A \cap M_\lambda$ is indeed infinite as well. This is because it is defined by $\phi(x, b)$ and the sentence "there are at least $n$ different $x$ such that $\phi(x, b)$" is true in $M$, and thus in $M_\lambda$, for all $n \in \mathbb{N}$.

Comment: Can this solution be extended to the case $A \subset M^n$?  I cannot see how.

Comment: @Kat yes, the exact same proof works for the case $A \subseteq M^n$. You just have to replace the use single elements by finite tuples everywhere (as I indicated at the start of my answer). Often in model theory we do not distinguish between single elements or finite tuples, because all the proofs work the same anyway.

Comment: But we still want in this case $\Sigma(x)$ be a 1-type in M, right? It will be?

Comment: @Kat That is not needed, because if something is $\lambda$-saturated then it realises any $n$-type over less than $\lambda$ parameters. If your definition only mentions 1-types, you can still prove this statement from that definition (so it is equivalent). That may be a nice exercise (hint: induction).